# How to hide <select> and toggle (open) with a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and am trying to imitate jQueryMobile's select option where you can replace the standard select textbar and arrows with just a button which toggles the opening of said select.

I don't want to use dropdowns either because they get hidden inside my nested divs (if you can make them appear at the topmost layer, then that's fine too).

So I'm wondering if there's a way to have a button as a stand-in for opening the select options.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure on this, need a little more information. But you can create a button with:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Message')">Button</button>
```

if that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I need it to toggle a <select> when I hit a button. So basically a typical <select> tag except without the text and default arrows.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for but I did a search and found this plugin and I think if you were to experiment with this then you could come up with the desired effect. Give it a look over.

Theres a spot about a 1/3 of the way down the page which I think would help you decide if this would work.

Plugin: [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: Not quite, I don't want text to be shown, just an icon.

Comment: If you go to this section https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-options The options also use glyphicons. I'm almost certain if you just make your first one a glyphicon as show and not include any text then it will be just an icon. If the desired icon can be found in a glyphicon.